# JTable icon linked to object

Tags: java, swing, icons, tablecellrenderer

I have the following problem: i currently have a few classes representing various plants and animals, which all have base class "Organism", they are part of a world (another class, which contains a "2D" container of Organisms or empty fields - kinda like a 2D map of a world). Only 1 organism can occupy a world slot at the same time.

What i want is to draw a map of this world. In order to do this i have created a JTable, which uses world's 2D container as a data source. Now the problem is, i don't know how to make the JTable use class's own methods in order to draw cells.

Each class has it's method which returns an image representing it:

```
@Override public ImageIcon drawing(){
    return new ImageIcon("Guarana.png");
}
```

my table has following components available:

```
private String[] columnNames;
private Object[][] data;
```

I've created my own table model (following the tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

So the creation of table looks like this:

```
    model = new MyTableModel(testowyString, organizmy);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Organizm.class, new IconRenderer());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setBounds(210, 0, 780, 900);
    add(scrollPane);
```

As you can see i have tried to create my own IconRenderer (but for some reason the JTable still doesn't draw the icons):

public class IconRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

```
    ImageIcon sheepIcon = new ImageIcon("Owca.png");
    ImageIcon wolfIcon = new ImageIcon("Wilk.png");
    ImageIcon mouseIcon = new ImageIcon("Mysz.png");
    ImageIcon chickenIcon = new ImageIcon("Kurka.png");
    ImageIcon turtleIcon = new ImageIcon("Zolw.png");
    ImageIcon grassIcon = new ImageIcon("Trawa.png");
    ImageIcon guaranaIcon = new ImageIcon("Guarana.png");
    ImageIcon emptyIcon = new ImageIcon("Pusty.png");
public IconRenderer() { super(); }

public void setValue(Organizm organizm) {
    setIcon((organizm == null) ? ikonkaPusty : organizm.rysowanie());
}
```

}

(yes, the icons here are a part of my old code, when each class didn't return it's icon)

To sum up: i want to make it so when JTable draws a map it draws an icon using an existing method of a class which is linked to  cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of overriding `setValue()` you need to override `getTableCellRendererComponent()` and call `setIcon()` from there. The `value` argument will be the `Organizm` that is the table cell's value, so you can do this:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                  Object value,
                                  boolean isSelected,
                                  boolean hasFocus,
                                  int row,
                                  int column) {
    Organizm o = (Organizm) value;
    setIcon((organizm == null) ? ikonkaPusty : organizm.rysowanie());
    return this;
}
```

I'm assuming that `organizm.rysowanie()` returns the `ImageIcon`. Although if that's true, then your `setValue()` implementation probably should have worked. Another thought I have is to change your `setValue()` signature to `public void setValue(Object value)` and cast `value` in the method like in my example above. This would avoid method overloading issues that would result in calling the `setValue()` method with an `Object` argument instead of your `setValue()` method with the `Organizm` argument.